# Не работает замена букв на следующие со смещением

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Написал код. Суть: заменить каждую букву строки str следующей по алфавиту через одну, то есть букву A на С, F на H и т.д.
Код:

```
    str=('''g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.''')
str=str.replace('a', 'c')
str=str.replace('b', 'd')
str=str.replace('c', 'e')
str=str.replace('d', 'f')
str=str.replace('e', 'g')
str=str.replace('f', 'h')
str=str.replace('g', 'i')
str=str.replace('h', 'j')
str=str.replace('i', 'k')
str=str.replace('j', 'l')
str=str.replace('k', 'm')
str=str.replace('l', 'n')
str=str.replace('m', 'o')
str=str.replace('n', 'p')
str=str.replace('o', 'q')
str=str.replace('p', 'r')
str=str.replace('q', 's')
str=str.replace('r', 't')
str=str.replace('s', 'u')
str=str.replace('t', 'v')
str=str.replace('u', 'w')
str=str.replace('v', 'x')
str=str.replace('w', 'y')
str=str.replace('x', 'z')
str=str.replace('y', 'a')
str=str.replace('z', 'b')
print(str)
```

Вот что он выдал:

a baba aaa babbb bbabababa ab ba babb bbaba abab aaabababa aba bab baaba ab ab ba babb aa ababbaaaabb abb bbaba aba bbaa babb aa aa baba aaaba abbabaaaaabbaba aa baaaaaabbab baa abbba ab bba abb

Comment: что именно вас удивляет? код выполняется последовательно, сначала все `g` меняются на `i`, ниже `i` - на `k`, `k` на `m`, в итоге все нечетные буквы станут `a`, а четные `b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {
    'a': 'c',
    'b': 'd',
    # и так далее
    }

myStr = "a1b2 cadefb"

newStr = ''.join([ d.get(i) if d.get(i) else i for i in myStr  ])

print(newStr)

c1d2 ccdefd
```

Comment: Можно проще: `''.join(d.get(i, i) for i in myStr)`

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать ещё проще через метод `translate`. Для этого нужно создать исходный алфавит и алфавит для перевода:

```python
in_abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
out_abc = in_abc[2:] + in_abc[:2]
t = str.maketrans(in_abc, out_abc)

s = 'g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw ...'
print(s.translate(t))
# i hope you didnt translate it by ...
```

Comment: Закомментированная строка - результат работы? Она отличается от того, что на самом деле выводится командой print().

Comment: @Andrey Да, спасибо за замечание. Исправил её.